# How to insert multiple $_POST data into mysql database for same id in php

Tags: database

I have HTML table like below and I need to add a order quantity with other table data in to database for particular customer on click on insert button. Please any help me on this.

[HTML Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pRuu.png)

```html
<?php
//to view all calls 

include("connection.php");

$sql="SELECT * FROM items where agencycode='$_SESSION[SESS_FIRST_NAME]'";

$result=mysql_query($sql);


print "     
<form class='form-horizontal' action='addorders.php' method='post'>
    <div class='table-responsive'>
        <table id='pending' class='table table-striped table-hover'>
            <thead>
                <th>Item Code</th>
                <th>Item Name</th>
                <th>UPC</th>
                <th>RLP</th>
                <th>Inv</th>
                <th>Company</th>
                <th>Brand</th>
                <th>Orders</th>
    <th>Total</th>
            </thead>";

while ($db_field=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
      
 
{ 
print "<tr>";   
print "<td>" . $db_field['itemcode'] . "</td>"; 
print "<td>" . $db_field['itemname'] . "</td>"; 
print "<td>" . $db_field['upc'] ."</td>"; 
print "<td>" . $db_field['rlp'] . "</td>"; 
print "<td>" . $db_field['inv'] . "</td>"; 
print "<td>" . $db_field['company'] . "</td>"; 
print "<td>" . $db_field['brand'] . "</td>";  
print "<td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='name[]'/></td>";
print "<td>" . $db_field['rlp'] * 1 . "</td>";  
print "<td><input type='hidden' name='id' value='$id' class='formlabel' required></td>"; 
print "</tr>"; 
} 
print "<td><input type='submit' class='form-control' value='Insert' size='16'/></td>";
print "</form>";
        ?> 
 </div> 
  </div> 
 </div>
```

Comment: You request is not cleat at all! Can you reformulate it?

Comment: @Michael Thank you for Reply, i am trying to insert above customer orders into database with multiple rows for same custid.

Answer (score 0):

Order field is the only data that is going to be posted, and for the rest of the data, the user is not going to interact with it, so you only need to perform an update query:

**HTML**:

```
<input type='hidden' name='itemCode' value=' .$db_field['itemcode'] . ' class='formlabel'>
```

**PHP**:

```
foreach($_POST['name'] as $data){
    $sql = "update tablename set order='".$data."' where itemCode=$_POST['itemCode'] and userID=$_GET['id'];
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

The code below is not required, as you're getting the user id from the URL:

```
<td><input type='hidden' name='id' value='$id' class='formlabel' required></td>
```

Hope this helps!